# Can I reference an external JavaScript file in a PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript

I cannot seem to get this to work. I have a small JS file that switches banners depending on the time of day, but it seems that doing an external reference in my PHP file does not work. It works fine in an HTML page.

This is the code in the JavaScript file.

```
function getStylesheet() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 19) {
        document.write("<img src='images/banner_day.jpg'>");
    } else {
        document.write("<img src='images/banner_night.jpg'>");
    }
}

getStylesheet();
```

And here is the reference code I used to call the JavaScript file. Its in a PHP file.

```
<script src="http://beta.website.com/wp-content/themes/theme/scripts/banner.js"></script>
```

Everything on the PHP page shows up in the browser, **except** for the banner that I tried to call with the script.

---

Here is the entire PHP file code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<a href="http://bifffffdggdch.com"><img src="http://beta.dfdfdf.com/wp-content/themes/asdafd/images/logo.png" /></a>
</div>
<div id="shadow2"></div>
<div id="shadow1"></div>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="">df</a></li>
<li><a href="">df</a></li>
<li><a href="">fd df df</a></li>
<li><a href="">The asfdssd asdfds</a></li>
<li><a href="">sf</a></li>
<li><a href="">df</a></li>
<li><a href="">dfd</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="slogan"><big>"fasfdsads2005."</big></div>
<div id="loginDiv">Login Panel Here</div>
</div>
<div id="banner">
<script src="http://beta.adsfasfasfd.com/wp-content/themes/adfadsf/scripts/banner.js"></script></div>
<div class="sidebar">
Sidebar Content<br />
<br /><br /> 

blah
blah
blah
</div>

<div class="content">
Main Content

<br />
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br />
<br />

</div>

<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
        <div class="footer_column long">
          <h3>Cadsfadsfafdfsd.com All Rights Reserved</h3>
          <p>dsafasdfdffadffadsdafsdfsadafsdfsadfas</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column2">
              <h3>More Links</h3>   
              <ul>
              <li><a href="http://aadfsdfsdfa.
              com">asfsdfa</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://ItsNotch.
              com">ItsNotch</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://adfasfsfaf.
              com">adsfasf</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://twitter.
              com/safs">Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=10215yy20340498">Facebook Fan Page
              </a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer_column2">
              <h3>RSS</h3>
              <ul>
              <li><a href="">RSS Feed</a></li>
              <li><a href="">What is RSS?</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you think the problem is in your PHP code, you gotta show us your PHP code.

Comment: What is the output that gets send to the client?

Comment: Everything shows up but the banner

Comment: the output is just a banner image

Comment: You should probably remove most of the irrelevant PHP code to make it easier for those helping you to pin down the problem

Comment: 1) PLEASE don't use `document.write()` - it is almost never the right solution and definitely not the right solution here. 2) Your script tag needs a `type="text/javascript"` attribute. 3) Unless you are calling that function more than once on your page (and looking at the code I doubt you are) there is no point in wrapping that code in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Javascript to this:

```
window.onload = function () {

  // Uncomment this line to make sure the script is loading/running, then delete it
  // alert('Hello, your Javascript is running');

  // Declare variables
  var currentTime, bannerDiv, newImg;
  // Get currentTime
  currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  // Get 'banner' div
  bannerDiv = document.getElementById('banner');
  // Get create a new <img>
  newImg = document.createElement('img');
  // Assign a src="" attribute depending on the time
  newImg.src = (currentTime > 7 && currentTime < 19) ? 'images/banner_day.jpg' : 'images/banner_night.jpg';
  // add the new image to the document
  bannerDiv.appendChild(newImg);

};
```

And put it in the `<head>` of the document, so change

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ....... -->
    <div id="banner">
      <script src="http://beta.adsfasfasfd.com/wp-content/themes/adfadsf/scripts/banner.js"></script>
    </div>
    <!-- ....... -->
```

...to:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://beta.adsfasfasfd.com/wp-content/themes/adfadsf/scripts/banner.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ....... -->
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <!-- ....... -->
```

If it still doesn't work, one of two things is happening:

- Your javascript file is not actually at `http://beta.adsfasfasfd.com/wp-content/themes/adfadsf/scripts/banner.js` so the script cannot be loaded/run. Uncomment the first line to confirm that the script is running.
- Your banner images cannot be found at `images/banner_night.jpg` - make sure your relative paths are correct.

Comment: This worked, however I had to change the paths and make them absolute in the .js file... wonder why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you've actually got the `<script></script>` in your head?  I certainly can't see it there (unless it is in `<?php wp_head();>`?).

Having attempted to navigate to http://beta.website.com/wp-content/themes/theme/scripts/banner.js **it returns a 404**, you'll need to fix this issue first.

Remember that javascript is client side, and all you want to do with php is spit out the  tags somewhere for the browser to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

It might be path problem.

What is you images (full) path?
What is you page (full) path?

As it is now it looks for images directory beneath your current page. Is this correct?